# MySQL change view column from BIGINT to BIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this.

```
(BIGINT)     (BIGINT)
PLAYER_ID    FRIEND_ID
----------------------
1            2
2            1
1            3
```

I think I can make a View as

```
SELECT * FROM FRIEND F1 LEFT OUTER JOIN FRIEND F2 ON F1.FRIEND_ID = F2.PLAYER_ID
```

printing

```
F1.PLAYER_ID    F1.FRIEND_ID    F2.PLAYER_ID    F2.FRIEND_ID
[BIGINT]        [BIGINT]        [BIGINT]        [BIGINT]
------------------------------------------------------------
1               2               2               1
2               1               1               2
1               3               NULL            NULL
```

Can I make a View which represents those F2's existence AS BIT?

```
F1.PLAYER_ID    F1.FRIEND_ID    BACK
[BIGINT]        [BIGINT]        [BIT]
-------------------------------------
1               2               1     // exist (1 -> 2)
2               1               1     // exist (2 -> 1)
1               3               0     // no backing relation (3 -> 1)
```

UPDATE ------------------------------------------------------------------

Sorry the above query wan't perfect.

The query, with @Romil 's answer, must be written like this.

```
SELECT
    F1.PLAYER_ID,
    F1.FRIEND_ID,
    CASE WHEN F2.FRIEND_ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BACK
FROM FRIEND F1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FRIEND F2
        ON F1.FRIEND_ID = F2.PLAYER_ID AND F1.PLAYER_ID = F2.FRIEND_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT F1.PLAYER_ID, 
       F2.PLAYER_ID, 
       CASE 
         WHEN F2.PLAYER_ID IS NULL THEN 0 
         ELSE 1 
       end AS Back 
FROM   FRIEND F1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN FRIEND F2 
                    ON F1.FRIEND_ID = F2.PLAYER_ID
```

Comment: the second selection('F2.PLAYER_ID') is actually F1.FRIEND_ID. Thank you. Accepted.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *, EXISTS (SELECT * FROM FRIEND WHERE PLAYER_ID = F1.FRIEND_ID) AS BACK
FROM   FRIEND AS F1
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42836/2).

Answer (score 1):

You could try something along the lines of

```
SELECT F1.*, if(F1.FRIEND_ID = F2.PLAYER_ID,1,0) FROM FRIEND F1 LEFT JOIN FRIEND F2 ON F1.FRIEND_ID = F2.PLAYER_ID
```